# Why smooth keyboard animation gone after applying style on BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, with smooth keyboard animation.

### Important note

For unknown reason, in order to achieve such a smooth keyboard animation, `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` is used as app theme.

### TodoInputDialogFragment.kt (Smooth keyboard animation)

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import com.yocto.wetodo.databinding.TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding

class TodoInputDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        dialog.window?.also {
            it.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        }

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

### Output (Smooth keyboard animation)

[image]

However, if I want to apply style on the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, the smooth animation gone.

### TodoInputDialogFragment.kt (Not smooth keyboard animation)

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import com.yocto.wetodo.R
import com.yocto.wetodo.databinding.TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding

class TodoInputDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.TodoInputDialogFragment)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        dialog.window?.also {
            it.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        }

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

### styles.xml (Not smooth keyboard animation)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="TodoInputDialogFragment" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

### Output (Not smooth keyboard animation)

[image]

May I know why there is such a behavior? How can we able to apply style on BottomSheetDialogFragment, yet retain the smooth keyboard animation?